# vim: disable greek letter mapping?

Tags: greek, vim, vim-latex

Anyone else find that trying to use

```
`something in quotes'
```

frustrating because

```
`s
```

is always mapped to

```
\sigma
```

Where is my mistake?

1) Shouldn't I be using (`quote') in the first place?

2) Is there a way of unmapping the back-quote to greek letters?

Comment: for (2) try adding `let g:Imap_FreezeImap=1` to `~/.vimrc`

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick. I don't know how I managed to miss this in setting up my vimrc. **upvote**